# Migrate XenServer instances to Hyper-v

Tags: hyper-v, citrix

What is the basic process of migrating virtual machine snapshots from XenServer to Hyper-v?  The virtual machines are Windows Server 2008 and Ubuntu Server 10.10.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article might help :

[Converting Citrix XenServer source machines to Hyper-V format](http://export.imix.co.za/node/90257)